# How to plot performance percentages using percentage on y axis and each metric on x axis?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, plot, scikit-learn

Let's say I have the following metrics which I obtained from an estimator:

aproach 1:

```
Accuracy: 0.492307692308
score: 0.492307692308
precision: 0.368678121457
recall: 0.492307692308
hamming loss: 0.0536130536131
Jaccard similarity: 0.946386946387
F-Beta Score: 0.902376921174
```

aproach 2:

```
Accuracy: 0.07692308
score: 0.307692308
precision: 0.8678121457
recall: 0.492307692308
hamming loss: 0.0536130536131
Jaccard similarity: 0.946386946387
F-Beta Score: 0.902376921174
```

aproach 3:

```
Accuracy: 0.432307692308
score: 0.412307692308
precision: 0.68678121457
recall: 0.2307692308
hamming loss: 0.0536130536131
Jaccard similarity: 0.946386946387
F-Beta Score: 0.902376921174
```

This metrics where obtained like this:

```
from sklearn.metrics.metrics import precision_score, recall_score, confusion_matrix, classification_report, accuracy_score, roc_auc_score, auc
print '\nAccuracy:', accuracy_score(y_test, prediction)
print '\nscore:', classifier.score(testing_matrix, y_test)
print '\nprecision:', precision_score(y_test, prediction)
print '\nrecall:', recall_score(y_test, prediction)
print 'Hamming loss:',hamming_loss(y_test,prediction)
print 'Jaccard similarity:',jaccard_similarity_score(y_test,prediction)
print 'F-Beta Score:',fbeta_score(y_test, prediction, average='macro', beta=0.5)
```

How can I plot this different aproaches performance with matplotlib?. Let's say on the y axis the percentage and on the x the aproach?.

Comment: That depends on the method. If you get some kind of confidence score you could e.g. plot `precision` vs `recall` curves, or `ROC` plots.
If there's no confidence score, you can still plot the `precision` vs `recall` values of each method. Ideally you would like to have `precision` = `recall` = `1`.

Comment: Thanks for the support @cel, Do you think all the metrics vs all the metrics are possible to muck up using percentage on y axis and each metric on x?.

Answer (score 1):

@cel'answer is the correct one if you want to know what to plot. If your question is more about how to plot your numbers, `seaborn` has something called `factor plot`. Have a look at the tutorial [here](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/tutorial/categorical_linear_models.html).

You can easily produce a graph like this (pretend the x axis has labels, and they are `accuracy`, `f1`, `precision`, `recall`):
[image]

Comment: This seems that works pretty well... Any idea of do a more interesting plot type?. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: `seaborn` can do a ton great and useful plots, have a look at their tutorials